# Why am I able to flag my own questions?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation, flags

I just noticed that I (as everyone else) can flag my own questions.
There are fewer options (no *"spam"*, *"rude or abusive"* nor *"very low quality"*) to choose, but it's still possible to flag your own question as *"should be closed"* or *"duplicate"*.

I don't understand, if that is the case, shouldn't I just delete the question?
What's the purpose of having this options?

Comment: [See this question on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170427/394700)

Comment: Also relevant: [Flag and close my own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176386).

Comment: I've flagged my own answer, in the past, when an incorrect answer has been accepted.  Once I realised the answer was wrong I flagged it, so a moderator could delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all duplicates should be deleted. Some are useful as signposts for search: having some differently phrased versions of an important question increases the chances of a search engine finding it.

Also, not all questions **can** be deleted by the author. If a question receives an answer with an upvote, or more than one answer, deletion will be blocked. The author can still vote to close in such a case, if they recognize the question to be a duplicate.

Flagging is useful for other reasons too, for example to ask a moderator to

- migrate the question to another site;
- remove a chain of comments spiraling out of control
- investigate a suspicious voting pattern on the question
- ...